# how to hide spesific element from XML?

Tags: php, xml

My code:

```
$title = 'example';

  foreach(Feed('http://example.com') as $f ) {
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
          $feedToArray[] = base64_encode(json_encode($f)); // <------ hash result in new array
      }
  }

  foreach(Feed('http://example2.com') as $f ) {
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
        $feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)] = base64_encode(json_encode($f));

      }
  }

  $newArray = array_unique($feedToArray); // <--- remove duplicated hashed results

  // loop new array
  foreach($newArray as $hash ) {
      $f = json_decode(base64_decode($hash)); // <-- decode hash and use to echo.
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
          echo "<span style='font-weight: 600;'>". $f->title.":". "</span>". "<br>". $f->description. "<br>";
  }
```

I don't want to show some of the output because of its not relevant info to me. basically I don't want to show the title and description of the element with `example123`
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: compare your title `if ($f->title !== 'Ev 134 Oslofjordtunnelen, på strekningen Drammen - Vassum (Viken)') { echo results; }`??? Also update your first loop with `$feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)]`

Comment: yes, probably best solution. then I add this under if `(strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)`?

Comment: yes change `(strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)` to  what I wrote in first comment

Comment: so change `if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)` to `if ($f->title !== 'Ev 134 Oslofjordtunnelen, på strekningen Drammen - Vassum (Viken)')` and `$feedToArray[] = base64_encode(json_encode($f));` to `$feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

```
  foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=601') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
        if ($f->title !== 'Ev 134 Oslofjordtunnelen, på strekningen Drammen - Vassum (Viken)') {
          $feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)] = base64_encode(json_encode($f)); // <------ hash result in new array
        }
    }
  }

  foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
        if ($f->title !== 'Ev 134 Oslofjordtunnelen, på strekningen Drammen - Vassum (Viken)') {
          $feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)] = base64_encode(json_encode($f)); // <------ hash result in new array
        }
    }
  }

  //$newArray = array_unique($feedToArray); // <--- remove duplicated hashed results

  // loop $feedToArray <------------------------
  foreach($feedToArray as $hash ) {
      $f = json_decode(base64_decode($hash)); // <-- decode hash and use to echo.
          echo "<span style='font-weight: 600;'>". $f->title.":". "</span>". "<br>". $f->description. "<br>";
  }
```

Edit:

Try: for array value you can use only `json_encode`:

```
$feedToArray[base64_encode($f->description)] = json_encode($f);
```

and json_decode:

```
 $f = json_decode($hash); // <-- decode hash and use to echo.
```

Comment: yes, but I need to search for `Ev 134` as well, if not I get all titles in XML

Comment: OK, then use nested if(), first to search Ev 134, second tocompare full title